# Parse SOAP faultstring in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I am trying to parse in Delphi xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Delphi code:

```
program TestXML;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Xml.xmldom,
  Xml.XMLIntf,
  Xml.XMLDoc,
  ActiveX;

var
  XMLDoc: TXMLDocument;
  Root,Body,Fault,Node: IXMLNode;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    XMLDoc.Options := XmlDoc.Options - [doNodeAutoCreate];
    XMLDoc.LoadFromFile('test.xml');
    Root := XMLDoc.DocumentElement;
    Body := Root.ChildNodes['Body'];
    Writeln(Body.NodeName);
    Fault := Body.ChildNodes['Fault'];
    Writeln(Fault.NodeName);
    try
      Node := Fault.ChildNodes['faultcode'];
      Writeln(Node.Text);
    except
      on E:exception do Writeln(E.Message); // "Node "faultcode not found".
    end;
  finally
    CoUnInitialize;
  end;
end.
```

I guess the problem is: the parent node "Fault" has the namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" and has the prefix "soap" but the child node "faultcode" has no namespace and has no prefix.

How is it possibe to get an interface to the node "faultcode"?

Thank you.

Comment: `XMLDoc` should be declared as `IXMLDocument`

Comment: kobik, I tried to change the declaration to IXMLDocument, but it generates the same error.

Comment: try `Root.ChildNodes.FindNode('faultcode').Text`

Comment: Thank you, I found solution, I should use ChildNodes.FindNode('faultcode', ''); where empty string in the second parameter means empty namespace.

Comment: Make that an answer please

Comment: That's a lot better. Thanks. Adding in `XMLDoc.Options := XmlDoc.Options - [doNodeAutoCreate]` made a difference didn't it.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine:

```
Fault.ChildNodes.FindNode('faultcode', '');
```

where empty string in the second parameter means no namespace.